# How to differentiate between unit tests and integration tests in Buildr?

Tags: unit-testing, buildr, integration-testing

[The Buildr quickstart documentation](http://buildr.apache.org/testing.html#integration) has a section on integration tests should be written. It briefly says you can write  integration tests "[in] much the same way as you write unit tests."

However, it doesn't say how Buildr figures out which tests (whether it be JUnit4, scalatest or whatever) should only be invoked as integration tests (executed after `package`) and which ones are simply treated as unit tests (executed after `build`).

As a long shot I have tried putting (Java) JUnit4 test sources into `src/it/java` (the proposed location for integration tests in the future versions of Maven) but Buildr did not pick those tests up.

**Can somebody clarify what I must do in a Buildr project to have a test not run after `build` but only after `package`**?

Answer (score 2):

Any given subproject in buildr can only have either unit or integration tests. The location of the tests in the project is the same whether they are unit or integration tests. For JUnit4 the location would be `[subproject_root]/src/test/java`.

Unit tests are the default. You indicate that a subproject's tests are integration tests via the `test.using` directive:

```
define 'foo' do
  # ...
  test.using :integration
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Is this a design choice of Buildr or is this a known limitation?
SBT achieves this by having an overly complicated system of so called 'Scopes' and 'Axes'.
If it is a limitation is this going to be lifted somewhere down the line? It makes no sense to force a user to define a subproject with its own source hierarchy, make it depend on another subproject's artefact, just to run some integration tests along side unit tests.